# Add Providers MSSQL Linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, linked-server

i want add a new linked server in my SQL Server (14.3026.27) Linux Red Hat Enterprise 7.5, before i add a linked server to other SQL Database, but now when i want add a linked server to MySQL i cant.

I check my SQl Server linux and i found that i not had any provider in the section "Server Objects" i need MSASQL for do it i think.

My Question is How addproviders in SQL Server Linux? or can´t add linked servers to MySQL in my current server?

Any other information is very apreciate, thanks.

[image: options for linked server]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. To quote from [Unsupported features & services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-release-notes?view=sql-server-2017#Unsupported):

> The following features and services are not available on Linux at the
>   time of the GA release. The support of these features will be
>   increasingly enabled over time.
>
> Database Engine:
>
> - Merge replication
> - Change Data Capture (see SQL Server Agent)
> - Stretch DB
> - PolyBase
> - Distributed query with 3rd-party connections
> - **Linked Servers to data sources other than SQL Server**
> - System extended stored procedures (XP_CMDSHELL, etc.)
> - Filetable, FILESTREAM
> - CLR assemblies with the EXTERNAL_ACCESS or UNSAFE permission set
> - Buffer Pool Extension

Emphasis mine.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't supported at the time of writing.

The list of [unsupported features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-release-notes?view=sql-server-linux-2017#Unsupported) includes

> Linked Servers to data sources other than SQL Server

It also says

> The support of these features will be increasingly enabled over time.

If you have any relationship with Microsoft you may be able to speak to them in more detail about if/when they will enable the feature you want.